# Getting average of numbers in a row SQL (Sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, average

I have a table where each row has numbers and I want the last column to average all of the numbers in the ROW. How do I do this? The average is NOT for all the numbers in a column under the same header, rather for all the numbers in the ROW. Each row represents a different user, so if I am user 1 (first row) I want my average to be (2+3+4+2+6+3)/6 = 3.33 (displayed in the average column for row 1). I want to select a row after it is entered into the table and select the proper entries, average the numbers, and then insert the result into the avg column of the table but I don't know how to code this in python (particularly, how to select the individual numbers in a row). Thanks in advance for your help.

Table structure:
[image]

Comment: Please re-post the table structure using text. Lots of people just can't see the images.

Comment: `(header1+header2+header3+header4+header5+header6)/6.0`,get's more complex when those columns are NULLable

Answer (score 0):

Just use a generated column:

```
alter table t add column avg6 numeric generated always as
    ((header1 + header2 + header3 + header4 + header5 + header6) / 6.0);
```

That way, you don't have to worry about the value getting out-of-sync with the data.  It is calculated when it is queried.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/90ae4/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Alternatively, you can put the calculation in a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*,
           ((header1 + header2 + header3 + header4 + header5 + header6) / 6.0)
    from t;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I am getting an error with this though. RuntimeError: near "as": syntax error

Comment: @jlynn . . . It needs the `generated always` as well.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Do I need to call the avg column by name?

Comment: @jlynn You have to use a very recent version of SQLite to have generated columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of SQLite prior to 3.31.0 then you can't use generated columns which would be the appropriate solution for this case.

In any case storing calculated columns in the table is never a good idea.
You could create a View or run a query like this:

```
select *,
  (
    coalesce(header1, 0) + coalesce(header2, 0) + coalesce(header3, 0) + 
    coalesce(header4, 0) + coalesce(header5, 0) + coalesce(header6, 0)
  ) / 6.0 as avg_header
from tablename
where .....
```

to get what you want.

For your table you need an `UPDATE` statement:

```
update tablename
set "Avg" =  (
               coalesce(header1, 0) + coalesce(header2, 0) + coalesce(header3, 0) + 
               coalesce(header4, 0) + coalesce(header5, 0) + coalesce(header6, 0)
             ) / 6.0
where ............
```